# Rails association using OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

Given a `List` model with the following associations:

```
has_many :list_group_memberships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :groups, through: :list_group_memberships
has_many :users, -> { unscope(:order).uniq }, through: :groups, source: :users
```

Basically I need to return the following but as an ActiveRecord::Relation, not an array:

```
def users
  super + [user]
end
```

Ideally, the `users` relation would use an `or` scope, but I can't work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this without the union gem:

```
# app/models/list.rb
def users_with_current_user
  # Assuming `users` is the has_many :users relation on the list
  # and `user` is a belongs_to relation on this list...
  User.where(id: users).or(User.where(id: user))
end
```

This will automatically create an INNER JOIN on the list_group_memberships table.

Comment: That's great thanks! I went with `User.where(id: super).or(User.where(id: user)).uniq`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it using the [active_record_union](https://github.com/brianhempel/active_record_union) gem and the following:

```
def users
  super.union(User.where(id: user_id))
end
```

EDIT: I changed my implementation to use the solution posted by @mysmallidea